# How to correctly setup and include video.js?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, video.js

I am really having a hard time configuring video.js for IE8. [The docs just say](http://videojs.com/getting-started/): include the js and css file. Version 5 uses ES5, IE8 just supports ES3. Use this shim.

So my setup looks [like described](http://videojs.com/getting-started/):

```
<video id="video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin video-one" preload="auto" controls width="960" height="540">
  <source src="assets/video/test.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  <source src="assets/video/test.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
  <source src="assets/video/test.wmv" type="video/wmv" /> <!-- ignore this one -->
</video>

<script src="js/modernizr-custom.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<!--[if IE 8]>
  <script src="js/videojs-ie8.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script src="js/video.js"></script>
<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
```

But, when I visit the site in IE8, I get:

> "Error: the object doesnt support this method" in line 18139 in
>   player.js."

This is the relevant code in `function _logType(type, args)`:

```
  // call appropriate log function
  if (console[type].apply) {
    console[type].apply(console, argsArray);
  } else {
    // ie8 doesn't allow error.apply, but it will just join() the array anyway
    console[type](argsArray.join(' '));
  }
```

I removed the whole block for the sake of testing. Then, new error:

> "Die Eigenschaft "play" eines undefinierten oder Nullverweises kann
>   nicht abgerufen werden."

which I guess has something to do that a function `play` is called on a `null` object.

So, few questions:

- What did I do wrong?
- Why dont I have to upload/ specify a swf file
  anymore like in the older version?

Answer (score 1):

The IE8 shim script must be in the document head. The regular script can be in the body or head.

> To make things easier, we created a single file you can include for IE8 support. No matter where the core Video.js library is placed, this file needs to be located in the head of the document.

The CDN-hosted SWF will be used by default. If you want, you can override the location with `videojs.options.flash.swf = 'path/relative/to/page.swf'`.

Comment: thanks for your answer! how do you know the swf part? is it said in the docs somewhere?

Comment: That part's probably not as well diviners as it should be right now.

Comment: But where can I get information like that? I dont find anything in the docs.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far, the errors are gone but now I get the error that "no compatible source was found for this video". Any ideas?